# Get event data from server in fullcalendar.js

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, fullcalendar

I am using fullcalendar.js plugin in my project. I would like to fetch event data from server.
Here is my fullcalendar config-

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
      eventSources: [
            BaseUrl + 'DTW/GetCalendarData'
      ]
});
```

And server-side-

```
public JsonResult GetCalendarData(string start, string end)
{

    return Json("[{title:'event1',start:'2018-09-25'}]", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Chrome developer console says  request-response is fine (status code 200).

But no event is displayed in calendar.

What did I miss here?

Comment: Instead of returning JSON string like that, use a class containing event properties and use `$.map` for assign item properties to corresponding events e.g. `event.start`, `event.end`, etc.

Comment: I think your code will just return that string wrapped inside an outer JSON object. MVC doesn't see what you gave it as JSON itself, it just sees it as a string, and then _converts_ it to a new JSON object, of which that string will just be one property. Just to test, try returning an anonymous C# object which can the be serialised to JSON properly, e.g. `return Json(new { title = "event1", start = "2018-09-25"}, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);`. Try looking in your browser's network tab at your AJAX request's response to compare the result produced by your code and mine.